# Выравнивание блока по высоте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Использую скрипт:

```
(function($){
"use strict";
$.fn.simpleEQH = function() {
  var maxHeight = this.map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).height();
  }).get();
  return this.height(Math.max.apply(this, maxHeight));
};
}( jQuery ));
```

Скрипт в плагине **SimpleEQH**.

Высоту блоков он выравнивает, но никак не могу победить проблему:
кнопки "купить и подробнее" не растягиваются по ширине блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - абсолютное позиционирование:

```
.zt_list_product .block_product .zt_product .zt-action {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
   // остальные стили
}
```

Comment: абсолютное позиционирование без использования скрипта?

Comment: Съехала цена на кнопки..